# Setting TIFF Image Resolution Unit to Inches

Tags: resolution, tiff

I am using the wonderful twelve monkeys library to create TIFF files, but I am having a problem setting the image resolution units to inches. I have spent 2 days researching both Google and the twelve monkeys source code, without success. I am hoping that someone else knows how to solve this. This is the simplified code:

```
final BufferedImage bufferedImage = someImage;
final int dpi = 300;
final String filePath = someFilePath;

final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF").next();
final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(buffer);
writer.setOutput(output);

final double resolution = dpi / 10.0; // --- This is a hack (possibly a MM/CM conversion)
final String standardFormat = IIOMetadataFormatImpl.standardMetadataFormatName;
final IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(bufferedImage),null);
final IIOMetadataNode customMetadata = new IIOMetadataNode(standardFormat);
final IIOMetadataNode dimensionMetadataNode = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
customMetadata.appendChild(dimensionMetadataNode);
final IIOMetadataNode horizontalMetadataNode = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
dimensionMetadataNode.appendChild(horizontalMetadataNode);
horizontalMetadataNode.setAttribute("value",String.valueOf(resolution));
final IIOMetadataNode verticalMetadataNode = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
dimensionMetadataNode.appendChild(verticalMetadataNode);
verticalMetadataNode.setAttribute("value",String.valueOf(resolution));
metadata.mergeTree(standardFormat,customMetadata);

final IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage,null,metadata);
writer.write(null,iioImage,params);

final File file = new File(filePath);
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
buffer.writeTo( fos );
```

This code creates a TIFF file which ImageMagick reports as:

```
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 8.26667x11.6933
Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
```

And yet com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFBaseline states:

```
int RESOLUTION_UNIT_NONE = 1;
int RESOLUTION_UNIT_DPI = 2; // Default
int RESOLUTION_UNIT_CENTIMETER = 3;
```

I know that I could exec ImageMagick from Java to set the required resolution units, but that is something of a hack and it would be much better to simply generate Tiff file data with the correct resolution unit from my Java code.

If my question is foolish (or I have been stupid), I apologise in advance. I would welcome any help. Thank-you.